# Update Ubuntu 14.04 to 16.04

Tags: 14.04, 16.04

I tried updating my Ubuntu from 14.04 to 16.04 and was faced with a black screen. In the end, i could only access the terminal. I had to reinstall the older version back. How do I safely update without experiencing that again?

Comment: How did you update?

Comment: after making an update, i was told that 16.04 is available. I tried and shot my self in the leg. That was 2 months ago though, but i'll want to update again and avoid facing that issue. Thanks

Comment: Very strange. That shouldn't cause problems. Please show `/etc/apt/sources.list`.

Comment: It could be many things causing black screen. You need to provide details of your hardware.

Comment: http://pastebin.com/bPDMDz1A @MarkYisri

Comment: Hmm, `/etc/apt/sources.list` looks normal.

Comment: as i said, i faced that issue 2 months ago and reinstalled 14.04. Could things be different this time?

Comment: Not sure, can you make a backup?

Comment: Not sure i can right now. I totally would have loved to avoid this. Thanks @Mark

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried updating again and it works. I guess whatever the issue was, it has been fixed by an update. No blank screen anymore. ;)